# Searching fast for a file in a large directory in Python

Tags: python

I would like to search for a file in Python, however, the directory where I am looking for a file consists of many subdirectories and hundreds of thousands or even millions of files. So far I have used the following code, but it is very slow. Is there a faster way to find a file?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_dir):
    for name in files:
        if desired_filename==name:
            ...
```

Comment: Would `glob("**/filename")` work for you?

Comment: Can you use the directory naming to help narrow the search? Or if you do multiple searches of the same directory structure for different files you could implement some sort of file name indexing.

Answer (score 1):

If `glob("**/filename")` approach suggested by @Shadow doesn't work out well, you may want to build an index for the directory you work with:

```
import pickle
from collections import defaultdict

# run this once
index = defaultdict(str)
for path_to_file, file_name in walk(search_dir):
    index[file_name] += '{};'.format(path_to_file)
pickle.dump(index, 'index.bin')

# load index
index = pickle.load('index.bin')

# run this to get semicolon-separated list of paths that end with the file
paths = index['my_file.txt']
for path in paths.split(';')[:-1]:
    # do stuff with the file
```

"Hundreds of thousands" of files isn't that large amount and will take around 10-100 Mb in RAM, depending on path length. I'm using `defaultdict(str)` to keep memory usage short and predictable, but you can also try `defaultdict(list)` or `defaultdict(tuple)`.

---

To get an idea of execution speed of this approach, you can try this:

```
>>> d = {
    'file_{}.csv'.format(i): '/home/user/data/{};/home/user/backup;'.format(i) 
    for i in range(500000)
}
>>> d['file_4021.csv']
'/home/user/data/4021;/home/user/backup;'
```